# Android Parse objects not showing on my dashboard

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I am sending Parse objects to my Parse dashboard to the Installation class. I can see the device token but the other 3 objects not shown below is my code please tell me where I am doing wrong,

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                devicetoken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
                ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Channel_name");
                testObject.put("user_objectId", "user_" + devicetoken);
                testObject.put("userId", 5);
                testObject.put("Gender", "male");
                testObject.put("Age", 24);
                testObject.saveInBackground();
                new DatabaseTableHandler().execute("TEXT");
            }
        });
```

Comment: And where is the code for showing `parsed object`.

Comment: I am just sending these objects to my parse web dashboard not showing on device. So they don't showing on the dashboard thats what I am saying

Comment: Show the code where you sending objects to parse web.